# Strange behavior of QgsScaleComboBox

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

I am using a `QgsScaleComboBox` and it's behavior is really strange. I also have 2 `buttons` in my gui for adding/deleting items. Those are the methods I use for adding/deleting: 
Adding:

```
    def addScale(self):
        newScale = (str(1. / self.dialogui.scaleBox.scale()))
        if self.dialogui.scaleBox.findText("1:" + newScale) == -1:
            self.dialogui.scaleBox.addItem("1:" + newScale)
```

Deleting:

```
    def deleteScale(self):
        delitem = self.dialogui.scaleBox.currentIndex()
        self.dialogui.scaleBox.removeItem(delitem)
```

I also store all items in the `QgsScaleComboBox` after the plugin closes. I store them like this:

```
    list = []
    for i in range(self.dialogui.scaleBox.count()):
        list.append(self.dialogui.scaleBox.itemText(i))
    QSettings().setValue("scales", ";".join(list))
```

And when the plugin starts I get the values back like this:

```
        if not QSettings.value("scales") is None:
            for scale in QSettings.value("scales").split(";"):
                self.retrieveScale(scale)
```

And with this method I add them back to the `QgsScaleComboBox`:

```
    def retrieveScale(self, scale):
        if self.dialogui.scaleBox.findText(scale) == -1:
           self.dialogui.scaleBox.addItem(scale)
```

I also have some predefined scales that I add with the `updateScales` method, it looks like this:

```
self.dialogui.scaleBox.updateScales(predefinedScales)
```

Now if I add a new item it adds the item to the `QgsScaleComboBox` but I can't select it. If I print the value of the current selected item in `QgsScaleComboBox` with the `currentText()` method it prints the right item. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QgsScaleComboBox**'s behavior is not really strange because you're not using adequate methods. I have a "test plugin" and I also put in it a **QgsScaleComboBox** and 2 buttons for **adding/deleting** items. However, I redefined your **addScale** function for printing **newScale** variable as:

```
    def addScale(self):
        newScale = (str(1. / self.wcbS.scale()))
        print newScale
```

It was printed at Python Console this value:

```
Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
1000000.0
```

after clicking in "Adding" button.

So, you're trying to add an integer existent value (for "1:1,000,000" item) to a string ("1:") and, afterward, into a **QgsScaleComboBox** object. Unfortunately, this logic error apparently doesn't seems produce a python error but it produces a strange behavior.

After searching adequate methods to use with a **QgsScaleComboBox** object, for including an arbitrary scale of "1:750,000" (not inluded in **QgsScaleComboBox** default list), I newly defined **addScale** as:

```
    def addScale(self):
        newScale = (str(1. / self.wcbS.scale()))
        print newScale
        print self.wcbS.setScaleString("1:750000")
        new_scale = self.wcbS.currentText()
        print new_scale
        self.wcbS.addItem(new_scale)
```

After clicking in "Adding" button, it can be observed at following image that "1:750,000" scale was adequately set, it was also printed as "currentText" (Python Console) and included as last item at bottom of **QgsScaleComboBox** object.

[image]

On the other hand, your **deleteScale** function seems to work appropriately:

```
    def deleteScale(self):
        delitem = self.wcbS.currentIndex()
        print self.wcbS.currentText()
        self.wcbS.removeItem(delitem)
```

as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

where "1:750,000" selected scale was effectively removed after clicking "Deleting" buttom.